# Make Default Checked Radio Button Value Display on HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

So I have my JS Function that checks if a radio button is selected, then displays the value on my HTML like normal.

**My problem is it only works if the default value is set to 0.** How would I change this so that if I use the `checked` option on $5 in my HTML radio input, that it will also display that value in my browser?

If I change my `checked` option to a different `tip` value, it still shows 0 as the starting value since I didn't click anything.

Here is my JS Code

```
window.tip = 0;

const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

document.addEventListener("click", ({
      target
    }) => {
      if (target.className === "tips" && target.checked) {
        window.tip = parseInt(target.value);
      } else {
        return;

        tipTotal.textContent = `$${window.tip}`;
      }
```

I display the selected radio button here

```html
<td id="tip">$0.00</td>
```

Here is my HTML Radio Buttons

```html
<input type="radio" value="0" id="tip0" name="tip" class="tips" />
<label for="tip0">$0</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="300" id="tip1" name="tip" class="tips" />
  <label for="tip1">$3</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="500" id="tip2" name="tip" class="tips" checked //here is the default checked option for $5 />
  <label for="tip2">$5</label>
</div>
```

So by default, my app will show the `tip: $5` option checked, however, the HTML on the browser for `Tips` will says `Tip: $0.00` instead of `Tip: $5.00` unless I click it

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use: `<td id="tip">$5.00</td>`?

Comment: hmm well I could, but if I change the checked button to another option, then I'd have to manually change it again to the other value I picked, but also I have it auto calculate based on the value of the tip for my order total, so technically it wouldn't work because the order total wouldn't know to add $5 if I hard code it

Answer (score 1):

It sets `window.tip` only when a radio button is clicked because you added an event listener that fires only on click. You can add an on load event listener.

```js
window.tip = 0;

const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    if (target.className === "tips" && target.checked) {
      window.tip = parseInt(target.value);
    }
});

document.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const selectedOption = document.querySelector(".tips:checked");
    window.tip = parseInt(selectedOption.value);
});
```

I also removed an unnecessary else statement in the first event listener.

**EDIT**

Automatically update `tipTotal` text:

```js
window.tip = 0;

const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

function updateTip(value) {
    window.tip = parseInt(value);
    tipTotal.textContent = window.tip;
}

document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    if (target.className === "tips" && target.checked) {
      updateTip(target.value);
    }
});

document.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const selectedOption = document.querySelector(".tips:checked");
    updateTip(selectedOption.value);
});
```

Comment: that doesn't change the HTML on the browser though

Comment: @joesono1 Well, your code also didn't change that. You can change it by setting `tipTotal` `textContent`

Comment: I added my code that updates the HTML, but when I tried to add your code into mine it didn't show in the browser the checked value by default

Comment: @joesono1 I edited the answer. You can see the updated version

Comment: I tried it again and the html for id=tip is still showing $0.00

Comment: @joesono1 I had `target.value` in the `updateTip` function which was causing error. Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got a Global variable called "tip" and an element with an `id` of "tip" as well. Elements with `id`s also become Global and so you've got a conflict in naming.

**Next, you need to initially update that `td` in your JS and also when the tip amount changes.**

```js
let tip = 0;

const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tipAmount");
const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");

// Initialize the table data
tipTotal.textContent = document.querySelector(".tips:checked").value;

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // No need to see if it's checked because clicking
  // on a radio button makes it checked and this code
  // wouldn't be called if you didn't click it.
  if (event.target.className === "tips") {
    tipTotal.textContent = event.target.value  // Update the table
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="0" 
         id="tip0" name="tip" class="tips">
  <label for="tip0">$0</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="300"
         id="tip1" name="tip" class="tips">
  <label for="tip1">$3</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="500" 
         id="tip2" name="tip" class="tips" checked>
  <label for="tip2">$5</label>
</div>

<table>
  <tr><td id="tipAmount"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but how does this display the value of the checked radio button without clicking it?

Comment: @joesono1 See my updated answer.

Comment: Why not `event.target.classList.contains("tips")`

Comment: so the updated line gets the value, but I need to divide the value by 100 and add .toFixed(2) to it. How would I do that? because I tried `(value / 100).toFixed(2)` but that isn't working

Comment: @doug65536 It could be that, but the OP only has one class, so `className` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply trigger a `tip2` radio button click event:

```
document.getElementById("tip2").click();
```

For example:

```js
const tipTotal = document.getElementById("tip");
const tipButton = document.getElementById("tip2");

tipButton.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
  if (target.className === "tips" && target.checked) {
    window.tip.innerText = "$" + target.value;
  } else {
    return;
  }
});

// activate click event on tip2 radio button
tipButton.click();
```

```html
<div id="tip">$0.00</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" value="5.00" id="tip2" name="tip" class="tips" />
  <label for="tip2">$5</label>
</div>
```